# How to use attach method in laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am attaching some files to a category in laravel 8, but it not work, the error is:

> BadMethodCallException
> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::attach does not exist.

I have tried like below.

**Controller:-**

```
public function updateSyncFiles(Request $request, $package_id) {
    $package_item = Package::find($package_id);
    $files = $request->input('files');

    if($package_item && is_array($files) && count($files)>0) {
        $package_item->files->attach($files);
    }
}
```

**Model:-**

```
public function  files() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(File::class, 'package_file','package_id', 'file_id');
}
```

Comment: Try to use `$package_item->files()->attach($files);` you forgot `()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$package_item->files->attach($files);` to `$package_item->files()->attach($files);`. When you type files with out parentheses it doesn't return an instance of the class.